# hipchat password not retrieved from credential storage

Tags: macos, hipchat

I am trying to use the OSX Hipchat desktop client v 3.3 (193). I have OSX 10.10.3. I have followed the instructions suggested by Hipchat support https://help.hipchat.com/knowledgebase/articles/166483-mac-beta-client-clearing-preferences

```
Close your HipChat app
Open Keychain Access (search for Keychain Access in Spotlight)
Click the "login" keychain in the top pane of the left sidebar
Click "passwords" in the bottom pane
Search for "hipchat" using the search box in the upper right and remove any     associated entries from the list
Open Terminal (search for Terminal in Spotlight)
At the command prompt, enter the following commands:
defaults delete com.hipchat.HipChat
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.hipchat.HipChat.plist
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.hipchat.HipChat
rm -rf ~/Library/HipChat
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/hipchat/
```

I am still getting this error [image: Password not retrieved from credential storage]

I am trying to figure out where on my computer an extra credential to delete must be hiding, or what permissions I have messed up.

I have access through the web interface but I would prefer to use the native app.

Comment: I recently upgraded to the new Hipchat 3.3 (which is probably the cause of this problem) but I have not upgraded OSX in the last few days.

Comment: Two things... This is off topic for StackOverflow which is why I voted to close this, and, something that you might find useful: pressing cmd + shift + 4 and then space allows you to take screenshots of a single window. Super neat.

Comment: @JustSid You're probably right but I have no idea what to do about it. What, if anything, do you think that is it on topic for?

Comment: [superuser](http://superuser.com) is the place for general software questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and exchanged email with Support.  They believe there is a bug in 3.3 involving port settings which will be fixed in the next update which is "due soon."  None of the above suggestions worked.

I had to reinstall 3.2.1 and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, try:

- quit hipchat
- restart computer
- reset your HipChat password through the web interface
- attempt to sign in to app

Comment: Did this work for you? Why do you think that this will help? I ask because i tried it and it did not work for my case, but if there is an underlying principle that I can use in order to take it further, that would be useful to me.

Comment: The first 2 are intended to cut out as much user error as possible.  i.e. some people might believe they're "quitting" an app, when instead they're just closing a window.  The password reset was to eliminate a password or database mismatch.  Hopefully someone on SuperUser was able to help you more!